# Программное добавление записи в дочернюю таблицу

Tags: c#

На win форме DataGridView1 с родительской таблицей и  DataGridView2 с дочерней и кнопка с добавлением новой записи. Требуется добавить программно строку в дочернюю с учетом выделенной родительской. Как?

Comment: Форма - это WinForm, WebForm или что? DataGrid - что за компонент?

Comment: Сорри, WinForm с двумя  DataGridView

Comment: добавлять надо через источник данных, но можно и напрямую - см. тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063825

Comment: Если через датасет то необходимо запоминать значение ключа текущей записи родительской таблицы и добавлять новую запись в дочернюю с учетом этого значения?